# Using the nativescript-plugin-firebase add an Event Listener with a Query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am building a chat inside my app using the nativescript-plugin-firebase for nativescript with firebase realtime database. I need to listen only messages sent to a user's account.

Is it possible to use the listener `addChildEventListener` with a query so to listen only specific messages (in this case the sent to a specific `user_id`)?

I could filter in the app the messages but that would not work since the amount of messages will be huge.

I know this is possible with Firebase, but, I'm using nativescript-plugin-firebase

```js
firebase.addChildEventListener(this.onMessagesChanged, "/chats").then(
      function(listenerWrapper) {
        var path = listenerWrapper.path;
        var listeners = listenerWrapper.listeners; // an Array of listeners added
        // you can store the wrapper somewhere to later call 'removeEventListeners'
      }
    )
```

The idea is listen only to the /chats that are relevant for a user instead of all.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should create a sub collections here. For example when two or more users want to chat, you should create something like a chat room as a sub collection to a document, then you should be able to listen to the sub collection alone where all the messages on the room will be posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding sub collections was the answer as stated by @Manoj